# Ошибка "picture should represent a valid URL" при расшаривании в facebook

Tags: javascript, ya-share2

Устанавливаю на сайт скрипт `ya-share2`. Задал все параметры, настроил разметку openGraph. При попытке поделиться страницей в fb - получаю ошибку:

> picture should represent a valid URL.

Пути в для `og:image` и `data-image` указаны абсолютные, с указанием адреса сервера.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, помогло указание протокола в атрибутах data-image и data-url. Т.е. не просто "//" а "http://"